# prevent user from enter non-numeric data in ASP.NET textboxes

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET web project using VS2010/C#, I have some text boxes which users should enter only numbers in them, how can I prevent users from entering non-numeric, floating point numbers and negative numbers in my text boxes? of course I can check entered numbers in server side code, but I think sending data to server and performing validation will take a huge amount of time, is there a way to prevent users from entering non-numeric values? or at least not sending data to server with incorrect data?

thanks

Comment: Its too late to do it serverside (the user already tried typing something). You can easily do it with jQuery - look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use some javascript and apply to the text box required, then it will not allow the others except numbers, see the following code part.

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
function onlyNumbers(evt)
{
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;

}
</script>
```

EDIT:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtNOD" runat="server" Width="52px" Font-Size="10px" 
 Font-Names="Verdana" Height="16px" Enabled="False" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers();"></asp:textbox>
```

Comment: thanks but how can I apply this javascript on my text box? where should I call it?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet , see the Edited Code for that

Comment: Hi @SaiKalyanKumarAkshinthala. Can you please tell me how can I update the code to allow period (.) as well. I have tried the following but it doesn't work. Thanks
-----------------------------------------
if (charCode != 190) {
        ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
        return false;
    }
    return true;

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET `validation` controls or write `JavaScript` to handle text/key events or even better try out `jQuery` or [pluging](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) to validate user input.