# prevent user from insert letter C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert, textbox

Hi I'm a beginner in Asp.net actually I'm trying to prevent the user from inserting letter in the phone number text box, I am trying this code but it doesn't work.

```
private void TxtBox5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch !=8)
    { 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: KeyPress is probably is too late. Check PreviewKeyPress event. Usually these kind of things are done in JavaScript isnt it?

Comment: That's a winforms event. You have to use javascript to achieve the same in webforms since you want to suppress keys when the client enters something in a textbox in the browser. But i'd suggest to use a different way, validate with ASP.NET validators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent user from enter non-numeric data in ASP.NET textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763779/prevent-user-from-enter-non-numeric-data-in-asp-net-textboxes)

Comment: Instead of looking at the duplicate you should really use ASP.NET validators, f.e. the `RegularExpressionValidator` with a regex you can find here: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be from winforms or wpf.
Try something like this in aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter valid Phone number" 
ControlToValidate="TxtNo" 
ValidationExpression= "^([0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]*)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

As most commented there, you have to use JavaScript function to enable this validation. Go through this stackoverflow thread which describe same scenario you are now facing.
[prevent user from enter non-numeric data in ASP.NET textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763779/prevent-user-from-enter-non-numeric-data-in-asp-net-textboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" FilterType="Numbers" />
```

Referance: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/ajax-filteredtextboxextender/